# AngularJS - directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am an AngularJS newby. I am trying to display an image using a template of an AngularJS directive and on click of the image I want a marker to be placed on the image. I Don't know why it is not working.

The first directive:

```
directive('hello', function() {
    return {
        template: '<img id="map" src="http://www.lonelyplanet.com/maps/asia/india/map_of_india.jpg"  />',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $('#map').click(
                function(e) {  
                    $('#marker').css('left', e.pageX).css('top', e.pageY).show();
                }
            );
         },
     };
});
```

The html code

```
 <hello>
    <img id="marker" src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png" style="display: none; position: absolute;" />   
 </hello>
```

Comment: a jsfiddle would be nice in this case

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are missing the `restrict : 'E'` option, by default `restrict` has the value `AC` which is attribute and class, in your case you are using the directive as an element.

Update: Based on comment

```
angular.module('test', []).directive('hello', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        template : '<div style="position: relative"><img id="map" src="http://www.lonelyplanet.com/maps/asia/india/map_of_india.jpg"  /><img id="marker" src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png" style="display: none; position: absolute;" /></div>',
        replace: true,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $('#map').click(function(e) {
                        $('#marker').css('left', e.pageX).css('top', e.pageY)
                                .show();
                    });
        }
    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6XneN/4/)

Comment: ok now the image shows up but the on click is still not triggered

Comment: its an image.it should appear where ever i click the mouse on the map image

Comment: checkout the demo, on click there is a blue image appearing

Comment: That's a sensible default. Even when I had this trouble before, I spent an entire morning with this thing again when things seemed to stop working magically. 

I think **a change in the angular version** used in the legacy code was the trigger of the "bug".

Answer (score 39):

Some other possible issues:

- The Javascript file containing your directive is not being loaded. This can happen if you're using Yeoman to generate your directive, and your index.html file is not modified.
- You are using a *camelCase* element name in your HTML instead of *hyphenated*. If your directive is called `widgetForm` and `restrict` is `'E'` or `'A'`, you should use `<widget-form/>` , not `<widgetForm/>`.

Comment: The widgetForm vs widget-form got me.

Comment: Thanks! Easy mistake for first-timers. Kebab-case vs camelCase got me too!

Comment: One more: don't start the name of your directive or attributes with `data`. There is zero error reporting, but it is reserved and will do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

By default when you make a directive in angularjs. if you ignore restrict property angularjs assume it as an attribute. as your html showing you should write your returning object as bellow

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <hello>
      <div id="marker"></div>
    </hello>
  </body>
```

and in angular the element is already a jQuery object even if you do not add jquery it will use its own implementation call jQLite. so you should only use

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('hello',function(){
  var linkFn = function (scope,element,attrs){
      element.bind('click',function(e){
        $('#marker').css('left', e.pageX).css('top', e.pageY).show();
      });
  };
  return {
    restrict : "E",
    link: linkFn,
    transclude:true,
    template:'<div ng-transclude><img id="map" src="http://www.lonelyplanet.com/maps/asia/india/map_of_india.jpg"  /></div>'
  };

});
```

i hope it helps [working exmaple](http://plnkr.co/edit/pkycXWamwlFJ2BbVvAs7)

Answer (score 1):

What @Arun said is correct. But it is not mandatory. By default ur directive will be attribute.

So Instead of using ur directive as a element

```
<hello>
    <img id="marker" src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"style="display: none; position: absolute;" />    
</hello>
```

try it as an attribute, like this

```
<img id="marker" src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png" style="display: none; position: absolute;" hello />
```

Comment: it displaying fine now, but the onclick is not triggered

Comment: where u are using the id "map" where is it? a js fiddle would be an easy way to solve ur pblm

Answer (score 1):

Don't append "Directive" to the first string argument:

```
.directive("someDirective", someDirective)
```

Should've been this for me:

```
.directive("some", someDirective)
```

At least, it should be, if you want to use:

```xml
<some>stuff</some>
```

Finding copy-paste errors is awful. Needing to find one is too... :'(